# Make class invisible outside of assembly

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers

Lets say I have class Dog:

```
public class Dog {
    public String Breed { get; set; }
    public String Color { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And a class Animal:

```
public class Animals {
    public Dog[] Dogs { get; set; }

    public Dog[] GetDogs() {
        ...
        return Dogs;
    }
    ...
}
```

The above to classes are in my class library and I added it as reference to my project.. Everything works fine but what I want is whoever uses this library should not be able to use class `Dog`, I mean he should not be able to do something like `Dog dog = new Dog();`. I tried to make it **internal**, but then, I must also write **internal** in `Animals` class and if I do this I can't use the GetDogs() method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make internal constructor for Dog class. `internal Dog(){}`. Then only that assembly can create `new Dog()`, but everyone can use Dog class.

Comment: This worked great but is it possible to make the user to not see this class at all?

Comment: If `Animal` class has property which type is `Dog`, then people need to see `Dog` to use that property. But you can use inheritance and make parent class/abstract class/interface visible for public and child class (`Dog`) will be internal.

Answer (score 3):

Change `Dog` to

```
public class Dog
{
    internal Dog()
    {

    }
    public String Breed { get; set; }
    public String Color { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

will produce

> The type 'Dog' has no constructors defined. Cannot access internal
>   constructor 'Dog' here.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to return Dogs you'll have to keep it public.
If you wish to prevent creating Dogs outside of an assembly - make his constructor internal.

Another option is to use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

if animals is the only class that uses dog then you could make dog a nested private class in animals and therefore only accessible in animals. But why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `Dog` class as `public` but its *default constructor* as `internal`:

```
public class Dog
{
    internal Dog() {}
}
```

Using `internal` on the default contstructor will restrict initializing it from the code outside the assembly.